# Should I create a new Activity on the OnCreate() method?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm currently developing an Android App, where in one Activity I'm calling a WebService and I get some results which will be displayed in a ListView. So questions time:

1. Im calling the WS from the onCreate() method, is here the way to do it? cos im still not sure about this.
2. If the result of the WS (which is a List) is just 1 element, I would like to create a new Activity passing this element (in order to skip the current view, as it is pointless), would this be the place to do it (onCreate() once again)?

Im still getting to learn the life cycles of Activities, but it doesn't say much on [Activity Life Cycles Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perform `WebService` calls from `AsyncTask` and update the UI thread from `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask`

Comment: a query - if you skip the activity on just 1 element - what will be back stack like ? will it impact user experience on return ?

Comment: If the user go back, it will return to this view displaying only 1 element. Cos at this stage, the onCreate wont be executed again, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

On the `Activity`'s `onCreate` start a new `Thread` or `AsyncTask` that performs any time-consuming action (like internet connections), when that is finished check if you received only 1 element, in this case start a new `Activity` otherwise display results on your `List`.

Also just for more user-friendly environment create a `ProgressBar` on your `Activity` that disappears when your connection is finished, so the user can see that something is running.